# How to launch directly to the post review page in Facebook iOS app with custom url?

Tags: ios, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I know that Facebook's custom URL scheme for iOS goes pretty deep, but I'm not sure if it would be possible to link directly to the post review page for a business.

### I can launch to the business page with this URL:

fb://profile/323276694418242

[image]

### But I'd like to launch directly to this page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have been attempting to find an answer to this for 2 years now, and the closest I've come is linking to the Reviews "screen" of the app by using the mobile web URL and not even the fb:// URL scheme.  For example, https://m.facebook.com/pg/PAGE_NAME/reviews/  If the person has the app installed on their phone, this works.  From there the user must tap the stars to leave their review.

Has anyone discovered a better solution, closer to what novicePrgrmr was asking originally?

Answer (score 0):

Some URL schemes are listed here http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook. There's nothing about URL schemes in official documentation, so it may be unreliable.

> fb://page/(fbid) will work to open to a specific page.

In [Reviews documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/review/) we have the following format https://graph.facebook.com/2345053339/reviews.

Try to derive URL scheme from this: `fb://page/(fbid)/reviews` or something similar.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of variations of that URL scheme. None seem to work.